# What could cause an HTTP GET to return 504 in code but 404 via curl?

Tags: node.js, curl, httprequest

Here's the code:

```
  var request, tmUrl;

  request = require('request');

  tmUrl = "http://archive.is/timemap/https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2017/01/15/rep-john-lewiss-books-sell-out-following-donald-trumps-attacks/";

  // this one works 
  request('http://www.google.com', function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      return console.log(body.slice(0, 301));
    }
  });

  // this one is always 504
  request(tmUrl, {
    timeout: 10000, // changing to 60s made no difference, 
                    // response comes back long before that 
    "User-Agent": 'curl/7.43.0'
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
      if (response.statusCode === 200 || response.statusCode === 404) {
        return console.log(body.slice(0, 301));
      } else {
        console.error("response code ", response.statusCode);
        return console.log(body.slice(0, 301));
      }
    } else {
      return console.error(err);
    }
  });
```

The issue is that running that request via `curl` returns the expected response, a 404 with this text: `TimeMap does not exists. The archive has no Mementos for the requested URI`. But when I run it in Node the response code is always a 504 and I have no idea why. My best guess was that the user agent was not allowed, so I made them match. Didn't work. I'm not sure what to do next...

The 504 timeout is always coming from cloudflare:

```
<span class="cf-footer-item"><span data-translate="performance_security_by">Performance
&amp; security by</span> <a data-orig-proto="https" data-orig-ref="www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=error_footer" id="brand_link" target="_blank">CloudFlare</a>
</span>
```

is that the issue, does cloudflare block programmatic access to sites in some way that I'm not aware of?

Comment: enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE , and compare the differences in the request headers. the secret lies within those headers.

Comment: Ah, I had tried that in curl but not in my code. Will do, good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A 504 request anyway does not return results as is a Gateway Timeout.
Why don't you handle it in your code?
eg.
if (response.statusCode === 200 || response.statusCode === 404 || response.statusCode ===504) {

Comment: But a 504 is a very different response than a 404. Why would I treat them the same?

Comment: depends on what you want to achieve. both 404 & 504 are error codes with no results. i made a small research and found that 504 errors are common to cloud-fare and you should double check your server's configuration and logs.